# Arkanoid en VB ... si añado un control, la nave ya no se mueve

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2019

Estoy haciendo un Arkanoid en Visual Basic como forma de practicar. Por el momento el Form1 solo contiene una Label llamada "nave", y a través de un timer y eventos de teclado controlo su movimiento.

Hasta aquí todo funciona aparentemente bien, hasta que añado un RadioButton que va a hacer de "bola". A partir de este momento, la nave ya no se mueve.

Adjunto código por si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim flechaIzq As Boolean = False
Dim flechaDer As Boolean = False
'Movimiento
Dim comenzar As Boolean = False
Dim izquierda As Boolean = True
Dim arriba As Boolean = True

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Width = 800
    Me.Height = 500
    'bola.Location = New Point(nave.Left + (nave.Width / 2) - (bola.Width / 4), nave.Location.Y - bola.Height)
    reloj.Enabled = True
    reloj.Interval = 30
End Sub

Private Sub reloj_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles reloj.Tick
    If flechaDer Then
        If nave.Left < ClientSize.Width - nave.Width Then
            nave.Location = New Point(nave.Location.X + 10, nave.Location.Y)
        End If
    ElseIf flechaIzq Then
        If nave.Left > 0 Then
            nave.Location = New Point(nave.Location.X - 10, nave.Location.Y)
        End If
    End If
    'If comenzar Then
    'mover()
    'End If
End Sub

Private Sub mover()
    If arriba Then
        'bola.Location = New Point(bola.Location.X, bola.Location.Y + 5)
    Else
        'bola.Location = New Point(bola.Location.X, bola.Location.Y - 5)
    End If

    If izquierda Then
        'bola.Location = New Point(bola.Location.X + 5, bola.Location.Y)
    Else
        'bola.Location = New Point(bola.Location.X - 5, bola.Location.Y)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        flechaIzq = True
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        flechaDer = True
    End If
    'If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
    'comenzar = True
    'End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        flechaIzq = False
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        flechaDer = False
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Como se puede ver, en este momento, todo el código que de alguna manera hace referencia a la "bola" está comentado. Tan solo añadir el RadioButton al formulario hace que la "nave" no se mueva con las teclas Izq/Der

Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que al agregar un radiobutton dentro de tu formulario, entonces ahora toda tecla es procesada por dicho control, ya que el mismo tiene el foco.

El label, no puede tener el foco, por lo cual toda tecla presionada va a parar al formulario, quien es el que tiene el foco.

Para solucionar esto, tenes varias opciones:

1. deshabilitar el radiobutton, de forma tal que no pueda recibir el foco. (enabled = false)
2. usar un picturebox con un dibujo de un circulo
3. usar el mismo metodo keyup y keydown para todos los controles

Comment: Muchas gracias!!